# Makefile:24: *** Unexpected opam version (found: 2.1.0, expected: 2.0.*). Stop

Tags: tezos-client

Just followed the instruction here https://opentezos.com/deploy-a-node/installation#install-tezos-dependencies-1

ran into this issue

Makefile:24: *** Unexpected opam version (found: 2.1.0, expected: 2.0.*). Stop.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Install, for instance, opam version 2.0.9. To do this:

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh
$ chmod +x install.sh
$ ./install.sh --version 2.0.9
```

Once this is done, you may need to remove/re-create `$HOME/.opam` directory.